# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I keep getting the below error and can't seem to get `.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')` to work.

```
eqs = soup.find_all('div', {'style': 'margin:7px 5px 0px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;display:inline-block;line-height:normal;width:120px;'})

for equipment in eqs:
    if '#b0c3d9' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Common\n')
    if '#5e98d9' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Uncommon\n')
    if '#4b69ff' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Rare\n')
    if '#8847ff' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Mythical\n')
    if '#b28a33' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Immortal\n')
    if '#d32ce6' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Legendary\n')
    if '#eb4b4b' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Ancient\n')
    if '#ade55c' in str(equipment):
        f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Arcana\n')
```

I have tried:

```
f2.write(equipment.getText().encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

and

```
f2.write(equipment.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').getText())
```

As well as some other things I am ashamed to post. Such as running it through the file that BeautifulSoup would later read from, but that just throws a different error. Thanks again for helping.

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#285>", line 1, in <module>
  import D2soup1
 File "D2soup1.py", line 86, in <module>
  test()
 File "D2soup1.py", line 30, in test
  f2.write(equipment.getText() + ', Immortal\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 5:     ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using string to parse out the box-shadow from the below html. I know it is probably not the best practice, but it was the only way I could think to grab it. Still new to BeautifulSoup.

```
<div style="margin:7px 5px 0px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;display:inline-block;line-height:normal;width:120px;"><div style="margin-bottom: 5px;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 4px #5e98d9;"><a href="/Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn" title="Pirate Slayer's Tricorn"><img alt="Pirate Slayer's Tricorn" src="http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/7/79/Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png/120px-Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png" width="120" height="80" srcset="http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/7/79/Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png/180px-Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png 1.5x, http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/7/79/Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png/240px-Pirate_Slayer%27s_Tricorn.png 2x"></a></div>
```

Comment: What is the full traceback? Why are you using `str(equipment)` there?

Comment: What attribute are those colours in? Why not retrieve *just* the attribute? Can you share a sample HTML snippet?

Comment: Added to show requested info. I tried coming up with a workaround using regex, but wasn't having any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `str(equipment)` without a codec; you are encoding the Tag object to ASCII.

Don't use `str`; get the text *once* as a unicode value. And use a mapping and a loop instead of so many `if` statements.

In this case, the `style` attribute is all you need to test against:

```
types = {
    '#b0c3d9': 'Common',
    '#5e98d9': 'Uncommon',
    '#4b69ff':'Rare',
    '#8847ff': 'Mythical',
    '#b28a33': 'Immortal',
    '#d32ce6': 'Legendary',
    '#eb4b4b': 'Ancient',
    '#ade55c': 'Arcana'
}

for equipment in eqs:
    style = equipment.div.attrs.get('style', '')
    textcontent = equipment.getText().encode('utf8')
    for key in types:
        if key in style:
            f2.write('{}, {}'.format(textcontent, types[key])
```

Most likely, however, those color codes are in an *attribute* on the `equipment` tag; look just in the tag value, or use a `.find()` call to narrow down your searches.

Comment: That is giving me a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` for this line `style = equipment.attr.get('style', '')`. Tried to edit your code to add a parenthesis at the end, but didn't work.

Comment: I added the first <div style> to the html code. not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Timmay: ah, sorry, there was a typo; `.attrs`, not `.attr`.

Comment: Still not working. I set the html to a variable in the Python Shell and ran it through BeautifulSoup. I then use the exact code provided to try to get the text and rarity, but when it finishes nothing is printed. Not sure if it's because I'm using bs4 or not. Should I update the question with the code?

Comment: Yes, plus a bigger input sample.

Comment: The input sample was correct after I added the first <div style> to the code. I think that is what threw you off, and had that been there you would have provided the correct code. Please change variable `style` to `style = equipment.div.attrs.get('style', '')` and I will mark this as correct. rereading the BeaitifulSoup doc helped me to figure that out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Done; next time perhaps provide more context to help solve your problem :-)